# What is the best option to store XML in SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql-server, xml, compression

On SQL Server 2016 (13.0.6300.2) we have one table that have two XML columns and around 1 500 000 rows. Size of table is around 150 GB. What is the best option to compress this table ? I was checking PAGE compression on dev environment but it saves only 3%. Is it chance that on Sql Server 2019 (planned update in near future) will be better ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XML data isn't compressed using page compression if the data is off-row. By default, the XML data (all types of LOB data) is in-row if the row is smaller than 8 000 bytes.

Unless I mis-calculate, you average 107 000 bytes per row. I.e., it is very likely that the vast amount of your XML data is off-row. Meaning page compression won't help (much).

SQL Server 2022 has XML compression. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/xml-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) (the XML_COMPRESSION option).